# Корректная структура кода в перехватчике http-запросов

Tags: angular2, typescript

Имеется файл `http.interseptor.ts` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEvent,
         HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler,
         HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse,
         HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class HttpIntercept implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept (reqest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (reqest.method === 'POST') {
      if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null) {
        reqest = reqest.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
      } else {
        reqest = reqest.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
      }
    }
    if (reqest.method === 'GET') {
      if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null ) {
        reqest = reqest.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
      } else {
        reqest = reqest.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                Accept: 'application/json'
            }
        });
      }
    }
    if (reqest.method === 'PUT') {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null ) {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        } else {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        }
    }
    if (reqest.method === 'DELETE') {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null ) {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        } else {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        }
    }
    if (reqest.method === 'PATCH') {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null ) {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        } else {
          reqest = reqest.clone({
              setHeaders: {
                  Accept: 'application/json'
              }
          });
        }
    }
    return next.handle(reqest);
  }
}
```

Хочу спросить не будет ли лучше объединить все условия в подобное:

```
if (
       reqest.method === 'POST' 
       || reqest.method === 'GET' 
       || reqest.method === 'PUT' 
       || reqest.method === 'DELETE'  
       || reqest.method === 'PATCH'
) {
  if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null) {
    reqest = reqest.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
            Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    });
  } else {
    reqest = reqest.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Или потом такое решение может вылезть боком?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учётом, того что токен нужен при всех запросах, то проще так сделать:

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('auth_token') !== null) {
reqest = reqest.clone({
    setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `JWT ${localStorage.getItem('auth_token')}`,
        Accept: 'application/json'
    }
});
} else {
    reqest = reqest.clone({
        setHeaders: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
        }
   });
}
```

и не проверять на тип запроса.

Comment: А если в будущем нужно будет к одному из типу запросов что либо дописать? Уже ведь станет не актуальна данная конструкция.

Comment: Хотя думаю вы правы. Что мешает уже потом дописать допольнительные условия.